# Warning Msg While Feching the Config Block

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

While trying to fetch the config block from the Orderer we are gettng the below warning at the Orderer side though we are able to successfully fetch the block. Can anyone let us know why this warning message is coming from Orderer side? Can we safely ignore the same?

```
2019-03-18 05:37:47.304 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 020 Error reading from 127.0.0.1:48474: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-03-18 05:37:47.304 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 021 streaming call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2019-03-18T05:37:47.295Z", "grpc.service": "orderer.AtomicBroadcast", "grpc.method": "Deliver", "grpc.peer_address": "127.0.0.1:48474", "error": "rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled", "grpc.code": "Canceled", "grpc.call_duration": "8.871178ms"}
```

Answer (score 0):

That warning is generally benign. It indicates that client does not *gracefully* shuts down the stream gRPC connection after fetching block.